# why does my dog go crazy when i scratch the bed while she's scratching it?

Tags: dogs, psychology

So my dog (an 11yo female yorkie) sleeps in my bed with me and sometimes she'll go on a scratching spree, scratching the bed. I guess this can sometimes be territorial or her just trying to make her part of the bed more comfortable to her. But then sometimes I'll kinda scratch it with her, with my fingers, and then she'll kinda go crazy, play biting me and what not. It's like it's a trigger to her to play. But is their some deeper meaning behind that?

Comment: the springs in the mattress may be resonating at some frequency that the dog hears, but you do not ... that may be what is causing the reaction